# Excel data validation with fixed letters and numerals

Tags: excel, validation, excel-formula

I need to set data validation on an excel cell to be a specific format. I haven't been able to figure it out myself so far.

The requirements are:

8 characters in length
first character is the letter B
characters 2&3 are numeric
character 4 is a dash -
character 5 is a numeral
character 6 is the letter V
characters 7&8 are numerals

Can anyone help me with this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Go to data > data validation and then choose custom and add this formula:

```
=AND(LEN(A1)=8, LEFT(A1,1) = "B", ISNUMBER(NUMBERVALUE(MID(A1,2,2))), MID(A1,4,1) = "-", ISNUMBER(NUMBERVALUE(MID(A1,5,1))), MID(A1,6,1) = "V", ISNUMBER(NUMBERVALUE(MID(A1,7,2))))
```

[image]

Formula breakdown:

```
=AND(
 LEN(A1)=8, 8 characters in length
 LEFT(A1,1) = "B", first character is the letter B
 ISNUMBER(NUMBERVALUE(MID(A1,2,2))), characters 2&3 are numeric
 MID(A1,4,1) = "-", character 4 is a dash -
 ISNUMBER(NUMBERVALUE(MID(A1,5,1))), character 5 is a numeral
 MID(A1,6,1) = "V", character 6 is the letter V
 ISNUMBER(NUMBERVALUE(MID(A1,7,2))) characters 7&8 are numerals
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
=AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("B??-?V??",A1)),SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(--MID(A1,{2,3,5,7,8},1)))=5,LEN(A1)=8)
```